# ARKit – Tap node with raycastQuery instead of hitTest, which is deprecated

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

In iOS 14, [`hitTest(_:types:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview/2875544-hittest) was deprecated. It seems that you are supposed to use [`raycastQuery(from:allowing:alignment:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview/3194595-raycastquery) now. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/world_tracking/raycasting_and_hit-testing):

> Raycasting is the **preferred method for finding positions on surfaces in the real-world environment**, but the hit-testing functions remain present for compatibility. With tracked raycasting, ARKit continues to refine the results to increase the position accuracy of virtual content you place with a raycast.

However, how can I hit test `SCNNode`s with raycasting? I only see options to hit test a plane.

| `raycastQuery` method documentation | Only choices for `allowing:` are planes |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Screenshot of documentation for the "raycastQuery(from:allowing:alignment:)" method] | [image: Screenshot of documentation of the possible options for the "allowing:" argument label, showing 3 different types of planes] |

This is my current code, which uses hit-testing to detect taps on the cube node and turn it blue.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        /// Run the configuration
        let worldTrackingConfiguration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        sceneView.session.run(worldTrackingConfiguration)
        
        /// Make the red cube
        let cube = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)
        cube.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
        
        let cubeNode = SCNNode(geometry: cube)
        cubeNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -0.2) /// 20 cm in front of the camera
        cubeNode.name = "ColorCube"
        
        /// Add the node to the ARKit scene
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cubeNode)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        guard let location = touches.first?.location(in: sceneView) else { return }
        
        let results = sceneView.hitTest(location, options: [SCNHitTestOption.searchMode : 1])
        for result in results.filter( { $0.node.name == "ColorCube" }) {  /// See if the beam hit the cube
            let cubeNode = result.node
            cubeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue /// change to blue
        }
    }
}
```

How can I replace `let results = sceneView.hitTest(location, options: [SCNHitTestOption.searchMode : 1])` with the equivalent `raycastQuery` code?

[image: Gif of the code's result. Tapping the red cube turns it blue.]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### About SceneKit Hit-Testing

Official documentation says that only ARKit's [hitTest(_:types:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview/2875544-hittest) instance method is deprecated in iOS 14. However, in iOS 15 you can still use it. ARKit's hit-testing method is supposed to be replaced with a raycasting methods.

There is no need to look for a replacement for the SceneKit's [hitTest(_:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522929-hittest) instance method returning ***[SCNHitTestResult]***, because it works fine. So it's not the time to make it deprecated.

Deprecated SceneKit hit-testing method:

```
let sceneView = ARSCNView(frame: .zero)

let results: [ARHitTestResult] = sceneView.hitTest(sceneView.center, 
                                            types: .existingPlaneUsingGeometry)
```

### SceneKit Raycasting equivalent

```
let raycastQuery: ARRaycastQuery? = sceneView.raycastQuery(
                                                      from: sceneView.center, 
                                                  allowing: .estimatedPlane, 
                                                 alignment: .any)

let results: [ARRaycastResult] = sceneView.session.raycast(raycastQuery!)
```

### RealityKit Raycasting

If you need a raycasting method for hitting RealityKit's entity, use the following approach:

```
let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)

let query: CollisionCastQueryType = .nearest
let mask: CollisionGroup = .default
    
let raycasts: [CollisionCastHit] = arView.scene.raycast(from: [0, 0, 0], 
                                                          to: [5, 6, 7],  
                                                       query: query, 
                                                        mask: mask, 
                                                  relativeTo: nil)
    
guard let raycast: CollisionCastHit = raycasts.first else { return }
    
print(raycast.entity.name)
```

Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75418011/is-there-a-way-to-let-an-entitytranslationgesturerecognizer-recognize-touches-on/75419095#75419095) to find out how to calculate an `origin` and `direction` of a ray.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! But is there a way to get the cube node from `let results: [ARRaycastResult]`?

Comment: Got it. So basically, if I'm still using ARKit + SceneKit, just go with hit-testing even though it's deprecated?

Comment: Nope. There's a replacement for ARKit's deprecated method. SceneKit's methods are not deprecated.

Comment: I'm still kind of confused. The replacement for ARKit's `hittest` is raycasting, but that does not work with SceneKit right? Only RealityKit.

Comment: And [SceneKit's hit-testing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522929-hittest) is a protocol function right? How can I do this with my ARKit scene?

Comment: There are 3 `hitTest()` methods for sceneView object (of ARSCNView type). One of them, that is deprecated, returns `[ARHitTestResult]` – it was used for hit-testing detected planes. The second `hitTest()` returns `UIView?, and the third one returns `[SCNHitTestResult]` that can be useful for pure SceneKit hit-testing against nodes. The third method isn't deprecated – you can use it for AR apps and VR apps. So your arsenal in ARSCNView for iOS 14 are 2 `hitTest` methods and 1 `raycastQuery()` method. Also, ARSCNView's session object allows you apply raycasting method for detected planes.

Comment: However, if you're using ARView (RealityKit's view that ARKit can use too), you can use only raycasting methods – `arView.raycast(...)` (returns [ARRaycastResult]),  `arView.session.raycast(...)` (returns [ARRaycastResult]),  `arView.session.trackedRaycast(...)` and 2 methods `arView.scene.raycast(...)`.

Comment: `hitTest` and `raycast` methods are not from protocol. You can use hit-testing for SceneKit nodes and you can use raycasting for RealityKit entities. For ARKit detected planes you must use `raycasting`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I wasn't seeing the third function, finally found it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522929-hittest).

Comment: @AndyJazz, actually, by using hitTest on the same CGPoint. I can get result from hitTest, but raycast returned empty array. is it expected? raycast can only return result occasionally ... in ios16. I can see hitTest is deprecated. However, I couldn't get the wanted result by using raycast.

Comment: Hi SKLTFZ, post it as a question (with your code), please.