# RealityKit – How to get the name of a node when the user taps on it?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

This is how my nodes and 3d model looks like: [image]

What I would like to accomplish is when I tap on the model when the app is running, I want to print out the tapped node's name to the console.

This is what I managed to do but it only gives me back the entity and not the nodes.

```
@objc private func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let tapLocation: CGPoint = sender.location(in: arView)
    let result: [CollisionCastHit] = arView.hitTest(tapLocation)

    guard let hitTest: CollisionCastHit = result.first
    else { return }

    let entity: Entity = hitTest.entity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of a node using `name` instance property:

```
print(collisionCastHit.entity.name)
```

Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66178149/arkit-tap-node-with-raycastquery-instead-of-hittest-which-is-deprecated/66178402#66178402) for details.

P. S.

`raycast(...)` and `hitTest(...)` methods ignore entities that lack a CollisionComponent.

Comment: Its not working.
entity.name gives me back an empty string.

Comment: 1) Entity must have a name (not an empty string), 2) Entity must have a collision component – `entity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)`.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/LrcJaBo
This is how my USDZ model looks like right now, and what I want to do is when the user taps on one of the node, for example on the picture, if the person taps on the "Humerus_1" node, it prints out the node's name.

Comment: Print an hierarchy of your `usdz` model (with `.name` instance property) – like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56736645/hittest-prints-ar-entity-name-even-when-i-am-not-tapping-on-it/59866900#59866900, or like this – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62532680/realitykit-what-is-steelbox-instance-loading/62548756#62548756

Comment: But I don't want the hierarchy, I want to know which part of the model the user exactly tapped on.

Comment: Then each part (I mean separate part) of your `usdz` model should be a ModelEntity with a `collision component` and a non-empty string for the `name` property. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68404663/realitykit-hiding-and-showing-parts-meshes-of-usdz-model/68411215#68411215